# Deleting item from a linked list causes segmentation fault because of referencing freed memory later

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a simple game that has a function where shooting an asteroid spawns 2 smaller ones.
I've ran into a problem when I delete an asteroid that was hit and then try to add 2 new ones.
Here is the code that checks for hits(for all shots checks all asteroids) and deletes asteroids:(I know code is big sorry:/ )

```c
Meteor check_hits(shot_node** head, node** meteor_head){
    Meteor meteor;
    meteor.meret = -2; 
    if(*head==NULL || *meteor_head==NULL) return meteor; //meteor.meret==-2 any of the heads are null
    shot_node* current_shot;
    shot_node* iw=NULL; //inchworm for shot
    node* current_meteor;
    node* prev_meteor=NULL;

    for(current_shot= *head ; current_shot!=NULL ; current_shot=current_shot->next){
        for(current_meteor = *meteor_head ; current_meteor!=NULL ; current_meteor=current_meteor->next){
            if(SDL_HasIntersectionF(&current_meteor->meteor.position , &current_shot->shot.position)){
                if(iw==NULL){
                    *head = current_shot->next;
                    free(current_shot);
                    current_shot=*head;
                }else{
                    iw->next = current_shot->next;
                    free(current_shot);
                    current_shot=iw;
                }
                meteor = current_meteor->meteor;
                if(prev_meteor==NULL){
                    
                    *meteor_head = current_meteor->next;
                    free(current_meteor); 
                    
                }else{
                    prev_meteor->next = current_meteor->next;
                    free(current_meteor); 
                }
                return meteor; //return data of deleted asteroid
            }
            prev_meteor = current_meteor;
        }
        current_meteor=*meteor_head;
        iw=current_shot;
    }
    meteor.meret = -1;
    return meteor; //meteor.meret==-1 => didnt delete anything
}
```

I'm suspecting that something goes wrong here because it happens when I'm simply deleting and didn't insert anything after that. The segfault occurs when I'm rendering all asteroids(iterating trough the list) and apparently trying to dereference 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee which is a sign for freed memory(or something like this.) So basically my list contains an already freed element.
I tried to debug it with a lot of breakpoints but didn't manage to find any pattern.

Struct definitions:

```c
typedef struct Meteor{
    SDL_FRect position;
    int meret;
}Meteor;

typedef struct node{
    Meteor meteor;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct{
    double angle;
    SDL_FRect position;
}Shot;

typedef struct shot_node{
    Shot shot;
    struct shot_node* next;
}shot_node;
```

This function is called twice after this one(meret means size)

```c
if(temp_meteor.meret>=1){
            app->meteor_lista_head=spawnMeteors_pos(app->meteor_lista_head , temp_meteor.position.x+50 , temp_meteor.position.y+50 , temp_meteor.meret-1);
            app->meteor_lista_head=spawnMeteors_pos(app->meteor_lista_head , temp_meteor.position.x-50 , temp_meteor.position.y-50 , temp_meteor.meret-1);
        }
```

```c
node* spawnMeteors_pos(struct node* head, int x , int y , int meret){
    Meteor meteor;
    meteor.position.x = x;
    meteor.position.y = y;
    meteor.meret = meret;
    meteor.position.h = 32*pow(2 , meteor.meret);
    meteor.position.w = 32*pow(2 , meteor.meret);
    node* uj = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    uj->meteor = meteor;
    uj->next=head;
    return uj;
}
```

Comment: Recompile your code with `-g -fsanitize=address` and then run it, you should get a crash with a nice report telling you exactly what line caused the problem, then you can start from there. Show the report here in your question. Also, add the definitions for your structures. Normally, you need a [mre], but if your program is too big and you are sure the bug is in exactly this function then it might also be enough to simply add the structure declarations (though one could argue that you could then just write a small `main()` to reproduce the issue).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Can I use `fsanitize=address` with MinGW? I tried to run it like that and it doesn't work. (I'm using MinGW on windows). I already had the `-g` flag.

Comment: Ah, I don't think MinGW supports that unfortunately.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli oh that is sad. I have a very basic tool provided by my university but that signals no errors when I don't get the segfault and it throws a segfault inside itself when trying to call it's dump function inside the function I just posted.

Comment: The posted code looks okay. The removal of the intersecting shot from the shot list and the intersecting meteor _are_ correct for a singly list list implementation. So, the issue must be elsewhere. (_Side note:_ I'd rename `head` to `shot_head` and `iw` to `prev_shot`--particularly the latter). Without more code, struct definitions, etc. my _guess_ is that the _returned_ [by value] `node` for `meteor` has dangling pointers.

Comment: Also, return-by-value for a struct is rarely used [because it's slow/cumbersome]. Based on the code, do you want to switch to a `node *` return? Then, you _don't_ do `free(current_meteor);` but _do_ `return current_meteor;`  Your code _just_ removes a meteor node, but doesn't add the two. So, you're going to `malloc` _two_ nodes instead of just one new and reuse of the intersected node. We _really_ would like to see your `struct` definitions. Also, the code that splits the returned meteor into two and then readds them to the meteor list would help.

Comment: I could try and reuse the node that's supposed to be deleted. I also added struct definitions as you've asked.

Comment: I'll also add the function called just after this one to clarify.

Comment: @CraigEstey yes my code does just the removing part as I tought separating the adding part would solve my problem(naive ik). I noticed that every time I get this error head->next is the problematic pointer that has the 4xfeee adress.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not making `prev_meteor = NULL;` after iterating trough the meteor list.
That basically caused the list to either link in a circle and create an infinite loop when iterating torugh it, or having a next pointer that was pointing to freed memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).